# Updating label on the main thread is not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, performselector

I'm trying to update a label while different tasks are proceeding. I searched and used different options and endup using this way but it still doesn't work:

```
[processStatusLable performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:@"Creating your account..." waitUntilDone:NO];
DCConnector *dccon = [DCConnector new];
ContactsConnector *conCon = [ContactsConnector new];

if (![dccon existUsersData]) {
    [dccon saveUsersInformation:device :usDTO];
    //created account

    //get friends -> Server call
    [processStatusLable performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:@"Checking for friends..." waitUntilDone:NO];
    NSMutableArray *array = [conCon getAllContactsOnPhone];
    // save friends
    [processStatusLable performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:@"Saving friends.." waitUntilDone:NO];
    if ([dccon saveContacts:array]) {
        [processStatusLable performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:@"Friends saved successfully.." waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}
```

The last `performSelector` is getting executed (at least I see the label text changed on the view), but all other selectors are not working. Any idea why?

**EDIT 1**

```
- (void)updateLabelText:(NSString *)newText {
    processStatusLable.text = newText;
}
```

Comment: Try waitUntilDone:YES, +if you can upload the methods you call from the @selector it'd be great...

Comment: maybe it is showing in the UILabel but it is changing too fast ?

Comment: it shouldnt the process takes like a minute

Comment: btw edited qeustiojn, i will test now waitUntilDone:YES

Comment: waitUntilDone:YES dont solved it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can use the following code to run something on the main thread,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  //set text label
});
```

Using that we can write a method like this,

```
- (void)updateLabelText:(NSString *)newText {    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       processStatusLable.text = newText;
    });   
}
```

Finally, you can use change your code this way,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    [self updateLabelText:@"Creating your account..."];
    DCConnector *dccon = [DCConnector new];
    ContactsConnector *conCon = [ContactsConnector new];

    if (![dccon existUsersData]) {
        [dccon saveUsersInformation:device :usDTO];
        //created account

        //get friends -> Server call
        [self updateLabelText:@"Checking for friends..."];
        NSMutableArray *array = [conCon getAllContactsOnPhone];
        // save friends
        [self updateLabelText:@"Saving friends.."];
        if ([dccon saveContacts:array]) {
        [self updateLabelText:@"Friends saved successfully.."];
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i replaced that with the 3rd performSelector and it just got executed after all methods

Comment: Yes, try this and let me know the result my friend

Comment: sry didnt soolved that too.. :(

Comment: isn't your property nonatomic ?  @property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *processStatusLable;

Comment: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *processStatusLable;

Comment: btw that all starts in the methode viewDidAppear, maybe its a hint

Comment: That's the problem. I changed the code a bit. Please try the new one

Comment: This doesn't answer the question;  it is just a different way of doing what the OP is already doing.  `dispatch_async()` to the main queue and `performSelectorOnMainThread:..` do the same thing.

Comment: <3 could you now explain me what that actually does?

Comment: <3 , Actually your code takes some time to execute as you said. It is not advisable to execute such codes on Main Thread. You are calling this inside viewDidApprear which runs on Main Thread. So I put your code inside dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ }]; that means, We run that part on a backgound thread. And at the same time we need to deal with UILabel. to access UI elements, we should run that part on the Main Thread, which is done inside dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{}]

Answer (score 0):

How fast do you run through this sequence of updates?  If it is faster than a second, you aren't likely going to see all of 'em.

Making them wait until done is unlikely to impact anything as the drawing is done asynchronously anyway.

Note that your method names are unconventional;  methods shouldn't be prefixed with `get` and `saveUsersInformation::` is discouraged (try something like `saveUsersInformationToDevice:usingDTO:`).

---

How much time elapses *between the calls to update the text field*?  The whole process takes a minute, but how is that time divided?

What is your main event loop doing otherwise?   Running modally or running normally?

Comment: as i wrote above, the process takes like a minute

Comment: How long do the individual parts take?